# Paste on TextField get clear when tapped or edited

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

When I paste some text on my TextField and I try to edit or cleae one single character it deletes everything. I did nothing special. I only paste a value and that's it. I putted a "print" on "OnChange" method to check if it identifies the pasted text but It doesn't. I tried many option but I didn't get any result. Does anyone knows how to solve this?

Comment: are you providing a textEditingController to it?

Comment: Yes. I provided a controller.

Comment: can u show the code for this text field?